# ONOS CLI does not work in docker?

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, onos

I'm newbie in docker and still trying to figure out how we can use **onosproject/onos** command-line interface. Maybe, it's only happening to me... when I try to use ONOS CLI from the docker, the command simply stay there, 'floating'. I get no output. It seems that I cannot use ONOS CLI from the docker instance. Could anyone help to figure out what's might be wrong? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where did you try the cmd. But for me it works fine, you may try this:

```
sdn@sdn-KVM:~$ docker exec -it onos-docker bash

root@be8c8289fe20:~/onos# 

root@be8c8289fe20:~/onos#

root@be8c8289fe20:~/onos# ./bin/onos-client

Logging in as karaf

897 [sshd-SshClient[309e345f]-nio2-thread-3] WARN 
org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at [localhost/127.0.0.1:8101, RSA, a8:58:8b:1b:00:75:cb:78:59:b2:89:69:42:0f:d1:f3] presented unverified {} key: {}
Welcome to Open Network Operating System (ONOS)!

     ____  _  ______  ____     
    / __ \/ |/ / __ \/ __/   
   / /_/ /    / /_/ /\ \     
   \____/_/|_/\____/___/     

Documentation: wiki.onosproject.org      
Tutorials:     tutorials.onosproject.org 
Mailing lists: lists.onosproject.org     

Come help out! Find out how at: contribute.onosproject.org 

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown ONOS.

onos>
```